# Haskell- function that accepts a list of functions

Tags: haskell

I need to write a function that accepts a list of functions, and a value, as parameters. Every function in the list must be applied, in turn, on the value.

For example, if my function is called `compFuncs`...

`compFuncs [f,g,h] val` equivalent to `f(g(h val))`

I can already tell that using a `foldr` would be useful here, I can put the `.` operator between each function in the list of functions and then apply it to `val`. However, I can't complete it, this is my attempt...

```
compFuncs :: [(a->a->a)] -> a -> a
compFuncs [] val = val
compFuncs (x:xs) val = foldr //Im lost here
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Two hints: (1) If you're using `foldr`, you don't need to have separate cases for `[]` and `x:xs` (2) What are the parameters that `foldr` usually takes?

Comment: Are you sure the type is `[a -> a -> a] -> a -> a` and not `[a -> a] -> a -> a`?

Comment: @psmears so I would do something like `foldr (.) x:xs`? but the how would I apply this to `val`?

Comment: @Bolboa by taking it's result and applying it as a functor: `(foldr1 (.) funcList) val` (notice `foldr1` instead of `foldr`)

Comment: Try writing it without foldr, then look at the definition of foldr and work backwards from there. Alternatively, inspect the type of foldr `foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b` and just look at what values you can insert where (turns out, there aren't that many possibilities).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(I believe you intended to write the type as `composeFuncs :: [a -> a] -> a -> a` as this is how it is used.)

`foldr` works by replacing the constructors of a list with the replacements you specify. For example, `foldr (+) 0 [1,2,3]` works by taking the list `[1,2,3]`, which is really constructed as `1:2:3:[]`, and replacing `(:)` with `(+)` and `[]` with `0` as follows:

```
1 : 2 : 3 : []
1 + 2 + 3 + 0
```

If you think about a list of functions `[f,g,h]` that you want to apply to some value as `\x -> f (g (h x))`, we can find a `foldr` by looking for replacements for `(:)` and `[]`. First, let's use composition:

```
\x -> f (g (h x))
= (definition of (.))
\x -> (f . g . h) x
= (eta reduction)
f . g . h
```

This is close, but we must do something with the empty list constructor. We need to replace it with some sort of "do nothing" or "empty" function. Luckily, we have `id`, which is guaranteed not to change the result in any way:

```
f . g . h
= (definition of id)
f . g . h . id
```

Now we can see the fold:

```
f . g . h . id
f : g : h : []
```

and we write it as:

```
composeFuncs :: [a -> a] -> a -> a
composeFuncs = foldr (.) id
```

By the way, types that can be folded like this with an element that functions as an "identity" are known as monoids*, and `a -> a` is the [Endo](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Monoid.html#v:Endo) monoid.

* There is an additional requirement that the function used to combine values, like `(.)` for `Endo` or `(+)` for `Sum`, is associative. You'll notice that this allowed me to present them without needing parenthesis above.

### Edit

For another way to discover this function, let's use GHC 7.8's new typed holes feature. First, we start with a definition of `composeFuncs` with some holes:

```
composeFuncs :: [a -> a] -> a -> a
composeFuncs = foldr _f _z
```

When GHC type checks this we get a type error, which I will reduce to the relevent lines:

```
tmp.hs:6:22: Found hole ‘_f’ with type: (a -> a) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a …
tmp.hs:6:25: Found hole ‘_z’ with type: a -> a …
```

Starting with `_z`, there is only one possible function of type `a -> a`, and that's `id`. For `_f`, we need a function that combines two functions to give a new function. That is, of course, `(.)`, so we write:

```
composeFuncs :: [a -> a] -> a -> a
composeFuncs = foldr (.) id
```